# How to solve conflicts with your root composer.json require?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I want to composer install filament/forms using `composer require filament/forms:"^2.0"` on a fresh Laravel 9 installation I get the following error:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update filament/forms --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires filament/forms 2.0 -> satisfiable by filament/forms[v2.0.0].
    - filament/forms v2.0.0 requires laravel/framework ^8.56 -> found laravel/framework[v8.56.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9.19).


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: `filament/forms v2.0.0 requires laravel/framework ^8.56`  - why not use a more current version of that package? Obviously, you did not use the caret as the version requirement, otherwise the error message would not read `Root composer.json requires filament/forms 2.0` (and the exact version 2.0 is indeed not compatible with Laravel v9)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 composer require filament/forms
```

without the `:"^2.0"` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

if i were in your this trouble, I'll change it **manually**.

**Method 1**:
**improve "filament/forms" version**: Check to see if there is a new version, If they already support higher versions, just `composer require` hight version

**Method 2**:
**change "filament/forms"'s composer.json manually.** by this case, filament/forms v2.0.0 can try `composer requires` "laravel/framework": "^8.56|^9.19". and run to test. if ok, sometimes i will submit PR to the repository. This is often because the author has not updated.

**Method 3:**
**fork and depend on your own private repositor.** This method is suitable for version conflicts and authors who do not update.
for example, fork this "filament/forms" , and change composer.json manually, If there are bugs or other some conflicts, fix them. and then change root(project) composer.json,  depend on your own private repository.

I will try to solve the problems in 1-3 order, I hope that will be helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).